# MongoDB datatype handling

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to handle numbers, which are stored as strings, like integers in mongodb?

e.g.

```
{
    "someKey" : "45646764646"
}
```

I would like to perform `$gte` or `$lte` operations on that value, but it's not possible as long the value for "someKey" is a string. I also would like to avoid of using a dbcursor and make comparisons with java e.g.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a direct query. You should be able to pull it off with a map reduce or aggregation operation. If you need to do these kind of operations why not just store it as an integer?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, if possible, converting the strings to ints when you store them in the database.  This could prevent confusion in the future, and would save a lot of space due to the storage differences.

Comment: string comparison with digit characters will not sort like numbers. it will sort lexicographically. "12345" < "2" which is *not* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your field someKey contains numbers, consider saving it as NumberLong() . Your driver should allow you to represent that field in your application as a string on most all 10gen drivers.